# Extruder motor not functioning after G29 command

Tags: extruder, diy-3d-printer

On my Anet A8 3 printer, running Skynet. When I **do not** use the `G29` command, Auto Bed Level, the printer won't print and just extrudes plastic in mid-air. But when I do use the `G29` command it will home and start to print but no plastic will come out. The extruder motor and the connector both work. Does anyone know what the problem might be?

Here is the start G-code I use:

```
G28 X0 Y0  
G28 Z0  
G29  
M190 S50 ;set bed temp (wait)  
M109 S200 ;set head temp (wait)  
; ------------------------------------  
; Layer #0  
; ------------------------------------  
G21 ; mm  
G90 ; abs  
G92 E0 ; reset extr  
M106 S0  
;segType:Skirt  
G0 F4800 E-1.0000  
G0 F300 Z0.200  
G0 X110.546 Y71.485 F9000  
G0 F4800 E0.0000
```

Comment: Probably inside the code there is a wrong parameter or the secuence is not correct, you should post here some initial lines to start printing to verify.

Comment: Have you found and fixed the problem? You may even add your own solution and accept that after 48 hours! If you have not been able to address the problem please update your question. Thanks!